# Smileys in SQLite databases

Tags: android, mysql, image, sqlite, whatsapp

I'm making a backup App for my different messengers.

The App copies (on rooted phones) the db files from each App, modifies the db to make it lighter, uploads with FTP and a PHP scripts copies data to a Mysql database.

Everything works just fine but the whatsapp Smileys.

When I open msgstore.db file on my android device with a SQLite reader in the "data" field (text) I see the smiley image, not a text equivalent (like in other Apps that I see things like (:  )

When I open the db file in my computer I see a square like char.

And when I open mysql I see nothing. Like if no data was uploaded.

What is really stored in that field as a smiley?  How can I see it in my computer? How can I get it to mysql?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change your database to use utf8mb4. I think you will find the following very useful for updating your tables to use ths char set. My guess is when you've restored the database they have defaulted to incorrect char sets.

https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4

Comment: Will this make my accents(áéíóú) unreadable? I'm a Spanish speaker.

Comment: Ok, I've tried this and I've made progress. But didn't succeed. Now I get mysql db to show me a ?. It gets data, but I think it's lost when PHP copies from SQLite *.db file to mysql.